# I have a Pymmsql error in python Query processor could not produce a query plan

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x

I have a issue reading my index select statement with this error any solution:

```
 File "src\pymssql.pyx", line 468, in pymssql.Cursor.execute
 pymssql.OperationalError: (8622, b'Query processor could not produce a query plan because of the 
 hints defined in this query. Resubmit the query without specifying any hints and without using SET 
 FORCEPLAN.DB-Lib error message 20018, severity 16:\nGeneral SQL Server error: Check messages from 
 the SQL Server\n')
```

Code :

```
    with pymssql.connect ("*********","*********", "**********","*****") as myDbConn:                  
                with myDbConn.cursor() as cursor:
                    cursor.execute(""" if exists (select * from sys.indexes where name = 'Micros' and object_id('payrolldata') = object_id)
                                    begin
                                        drop index Micros on payrolldata
                                    end """)
                    sql = """create index Micros on payrolldata(stono,payrollid,busdate)where busdate >= 's' and busdate <= 's' """ .format(dteStartDate,m0weekend);
                    cursor.execute(sql)
        
           
            
     DbConnect = 'Micros'
     myDbConn = pymssql.connect("*******","*******", "********",*******)
     cursor = myDbConn.cursor()
     cursor.execute("""select * from payrolldata with(INDEX(Micros)) ;""")
```

Comment: Your index / query make little sense. You are selecting all rows from your table - so the attempt to force the use of a filtered index (which does not contain all rows of the table) is logical nonsense. Are you thinking that the index will limit the rows returned? I suggest you start over - are you attempting to optimize this particular query?

Comment: Yes Im thinking that